# Компактная плагинация

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть код

```js
// делаем плагинацию
var imgPerPage = 5;
var imgCount = 100;
var pagesCount = Math.floor(imgCount/imgPerPage);
var ul = $('<ul></ul>');
for(var i = 0; i < pagesCount; i++) {
  var li = $('<li></li>');
  li.text(i + 1);
  li.attr('data-page', i);
  ul.append(li);
}
$('nav').append(ul);

// вывод изображений выбранной страницы
function showPage(pageNum) {
  var div = $('<div></div>');
  div.addClass('content');
  for(var i = 0; i < imgPerPage; i++) {
    var img = $('<img>');
    img.attr('src', 'https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/' + (pageNum*imgPerPage + i) + '/5.0');
    div.append(img);
  }
  $('.content').replaceWith(div);
  $('li').removeClass('active');
  $('li[data-page='+pageNum+']').addClass('active');
}

$('body').on('click', 'li', function() {
  showPage(+$(this).attr('data-page'));
});
showPage(0);
```

```css
li {
text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 3px;
}
li.active {
cursor: default;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav></nav>
<div class="content"></div>
```

Но при большом количестве страниц это выглядит не очень. Как сделать чтоб ссылки на страницы с картинками отображались от текущей на 5 страниц назад и вперёд, с кнопками первая и последняя страница?

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  background: #eee;
}
.tiles {
  width:900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  
}
.tiles .tile {
  padding:10px;
  box-shadow:0 0 60px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  margin:10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background:#fff;
  border-radius:10px;
  float:left;
}
.tiles .tile .title {
  font-family:garamond;
}
.tiles .tile .desc {
  color:#444;
}
.col {
  width:33.3333%;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="tiles">
  <div class="col col-1">
    <div class="tile">
      <div class="title">
        <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
        
      </div>
      <div class="desc">
        Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias, praesentium?  Id praesentium autem nemo hic aspernatur asperiores provident doloremque reiciendis magni, natus earum est?Voluptatibus perferendis mollitia pariatur! Eius, architecto! Id praesentium autem nemo hic aspernatur asperiores provident doloremque reiciendis magni, natus earum est?
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tile">
      <div class="title">
        <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
        
      </div>
      <div class="desc">
        Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias, praesentium?  Id praesentium autem nemo hic aspernatur asperiores provident doloremque reiciendis magni, natus earum est?Voluptatibus perferendis mollitia pariatur! Eius, architecto! Id praesentium autem nemo hic aspernatur asperiores provident doloremque reiciendis magni, natus earum est?
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
   <div class="col col-1">
    <div class="tile">
      <div class="title">
        <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
        
      </div>
      <div class="desc">
        Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias, praesentium? Voluptatibus perferendis mollitia pariatur! mollitia pariatur! mollitia pariatur! Eius, architecto! Id praesentium autem nemo hic aspernatur asperiores provident doloremque reiciendis magni, natus earum est?
      </div>
    </div>
     <div class="tile">
      <div class="title">
        <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
        
      </div>
      <div class="desc">
        Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias, praesentium?  Id praesentium autem nemo hic aspernatur asperiores provident doloremque reiciendis magni, natus earum est?Voluptatibus perferendis mollitia pariatur! Eius, architecto! Id praesentium autem nemo hic aspernatur asperiores provident doloremque reiciendis magni, natus earum est?
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
   <div class="col col-1">
    <div class="tile">
      <div class="title">
        <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
        
      </div>
      <div class="desc">
        Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias, praesentium? Voluptatibus perferendis mollitia pariatur! Eius, architecto! Id praesentium autem nemo hic aspernatur asperiores provident doloremque reiciendis magni, natus earum est?
      </div>
    </div>
      <div class="tile">
      <div class="title">
        <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
        
      </div>
      <div class="desc">
        Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias, praesentium? Voluptatibus perferendis mollitia pariatur! Eius, architecto! Id praesentium autem nemo hic aspernatur asperiores provident doloremque reiciendis magni, natus earum est?
        Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias, praesentium? Voluptatibus perferendis mollitia pariatur! Eius, architecto! Id praesentium autem nemo hic aspernatur asperiores provident doloremque reiciendis magni, natus earum est?
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```